# Are the login rewards random?

Tags: warframe

Every day that you log into Warframe, you get some sort of reward (blueprints, coupons for money off of Platinum, random ingredients, credits, etc).

How random are these? I know there are "milestone" ones at every certain number of days (I think every 50 days) that seem to be the same for everyone, but what about the rest? Is there any pattern to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that login reward drop chances are not released (if anyone can find something to the contrary, I'd love to know!)  At the very least, login rewards do not seem to appear in [the official DE-maintained drop-rate list](https://n8k6e2y6.ssl.hwcdn.net/repos/hnfvc0o3jnfvc873njb03enrf56.html).

*As far as we can tell,* login rewards seem to be a random choice from a pool of rewards (excluding every 50th day, which has a set reward, like you noted).

The Wiki states that "the chances of more frequently acquiring rare and higher value items increases as players increase their Mastery Rank," but I am unable to find any source for this.

Also anecdotally, people seem to report better chances of a high platinum discount after taking a week or so off.  I'd imagine DE is very interested in not making that public, if that's the case.

Comment: I wondered, mostly because I got a blueprint the other day that someone else playing who has played more than me never got through login reward. So that started me wondering. I can see why they might not release details, if how long it's been since you've played factors in.

Comment: @Ash The blueprints you get through login rewards are normal ones you can buy through the in-game market or Dojo for credits **except** for the milestone blueprints.

Comment: @Powerlord I figured they weren't special and were otherwise acquirable, it was more that he hadn't gotten it through login and I had, so we started kinda wondering what the setup was for login rewards in general.

Comment: @Ash "blueprint" is one of the things it can randomly select for you, and if that is chosen, it will randomly pick a blueprint for something you don't already have.